# Cookie consent in Android apps?

Tags: android, cookies

I have receive an email from Goolge about implement a cookie consent in my sites. I only have an Android app published in the Play Store. It uses ads for monetization. It is necessary to implement a cookie consent message??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will if you use any third party services - Google Analytics, Adsense, FB login, etc.

Read more here, it specifically gives examples of app implementation :

http://www.cookiechoices.org/

Comment: I have been looking for an app that shows a message of cookie consent on the market when app starts, but i haven seen any one. This is what i was confused about it. Thanks I'll implement it.

Comment: I can not finf any text example of text agreement on this page, have you any other link ?